# p:selectOneMenu Problem?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

The following code works fine for `h:selectOneMenu` but doesn't work for `p:selectOneMenu`

**There is no item in `p:selectOneMenu`**

**Facelet**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
      <h:selectOneMenu value="#{testBean.name}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.names}"/>
      </h:selectOneMenu>

      <p:selectOneMenu value="#{testBean.name}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.names}"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

**Bean**

```
package net.footfeed.beans;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean {

  private String name = "name1";
  private String[] names = new String[] {"name1", "name2", "name2"};

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String[] getNames() {
    return names;
  }

}
```

Comment: As BalusC said you should report it to them since it's clearly a bug in PrimeFaces (or ask about it on their forum, they answer pretty quickly). What I can recommend you is to stay away from PF3.0 if you are working on any serious project. I've ben using it for several months now and I have to say it is way too early for them to be production ready. On the other hand they are still in the beta, so no wonder! Also, don't want to offend anyone, but I downloaded their source code and the quality leaves a lot to be desired...

Answer (score 1):

Curious, it doesn't support a `List<T>` or `T[]` on `<f:selectItems>`. You'd need to to create a `List<SelectItem>` or `SelectItem[]` or, better, to explicitly specify the `var` attribute. This works with `List<T>` only.

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.names}" var="name" itemValue="#{name}" itemLabel="#{name}" />
```

with

```
private List<String> names = Arrays.asList("name1", "name2", "name3");
```

Since this makes no sense, I'd suggest to report this issue to their issue tracker.

More curious, when I omit the `itemLabel` (which should then just display the `itemValue` as label), it throws a pretty serious NPE on Tomcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.write(CoyoteWriter.java:182)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.write(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.write(HtmlResponseWriter.java:666)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeSelectItems(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:261)
```

PrimeFaces 3.0 is clearly still in beta stage.

Comment: I've tried specifying ` var ` but didn't work! I need to check `ListItem[]`, by the way it has been already reported.

Comment: What is your favorite AJAX library for JSF 2.0?

Comment: Oh, I used `List<T>` in my test bean, it indeed doesn't work with `T[]`! I updated the answer.

Comment: I have not really a favourite component library. I just look what I need right now and what component library offers the best right now :)